# Negative deletion votes count

Tags: bug, vote-to-delete

I have faced this strange issue:

> [image]

As you can see, I've got expiration alert (red box in the bottom) and confirmation dialog which indicates that I have `-4` deletion votes count.

I'm not sure how that happened and obviously it's a bug (well, I'm sure that I had remaining votes today, but even if it's not so, then at least it's a bug on `0 -> -4` deletion votes count).

Comment: I don't suppose you mysteriously lost about 500 reputation in the middle of the day and got it back later without it showing on your graph?

Comment: @Wooble not sure I got that. What does reputation have to do with this issue?

Comment: Users with higher reputation have more deletion votes per day. If you somehow were legitimately allowed to vote to delete 19 posts and did so, but later dropped to only have 15 votes, those numbers would make sense.

Comment: @Wooble oh, that. No, of course not. More, I can reproduce it (checked just now - no matter what's the question - if it's delete-able, then dialog box shows -4 del-votes count)