# Vote to delete this post? (-1 votes remaining)

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

I have just exceeded 21K rep and that means I would get another delete vote for the day. I thought I would go around and see if I can cast a vote on some post.

This screen was awaiting me:

[image]

Instead of +1 vote, I got -1. Why is that?

The following post seems to be a related at first glance, but on the other hand, I cannot personally reproduce that one:

[Negative deletion votes count](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254504/negative-deletion-votes-count)

I have never seen this issue before, just for the given reputation level exceeded today.

That makes me think that this *may* not be a duplicate, and based on the date difference, the other issue *may* have been already fixed.

Comment: related? [Negative deletion votes count](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254504/negative-deletion-votes-count)

Comment: @OGHaza: yeah, saw that, thanks. I wonder if that is related or a different delete vote count issue. I could not reproduce that issue and I got this one only when exceeding the given reputation level. Seems that post has not got a solution from the Stack Overflow crew either.

Comment: @Final, I couldn't work out if it was a duplicate. Was about to vtc, then commented "closely related:" instead, then edited to "related:", then "related?" ;)